# How to call two AWS methods with a single request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am doing a project in which in call two methods separately from Boto3 (AWS SDK for Python); in which each request lasts 1 second on average. So, I was thinking that I could reduce the response time if I somehow make AWS call the two methods consecutively with a single request to AWS's servers.

To exemplify, I am calling detect_faces() and search_faces_by_image() methods this way, in which process argument1 into response2 lasts 2 seconds:

```
// input: argument1
response1 = detect_faces(argument1)
// process response1 into argument2
response2 = search_faces_by_image(argument2)
// output: response2
```

I would like to make a single request in which it would call both methods and give me the response:

```
// input: argument1
response2 = custom_aws_method(argument1)
// output: response2
```

Browsing along the Internet, my best finding was that I could upload argument1 into a S3 Bucket, use Lambda service to do the processing and get a response with an e-mail through the SNS service. However, this way, I think that the response time would not reduce, since I would have to fetch the e-mail to get my plain response on Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the output of the first request is required as the input to the second request. Therefore, the same total time is required for the operations. If your goal is to **reduce the total time required**, then this goal is not possible.

However, if you have *multiple* such requests, then you could **use multi-threading to issue API calls in parallel** rather than in sequence. This is useful when performing multiple long-running operations, such as file uploads/downloads.